# How to zoom in/out in Xcode 4.1 Interface Builder window to see multiple UIViews

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm building a xib with multiple views, one oriented for landscape and another for portrait. I'd like to be able to zoom out from the Interface Builder window to see both and then zoom in on one of the views to work on it, rinse, repeat. Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136624/cannot-zoom-in-and-out-of-nib-in-the-new-interface-builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as far as I know, but Xcode 4.2 allows you to develop your iOS applications using ["storyboards"](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html), which is similar (and has many other benefits).

Comment: Thanks for the response Nathanial. Hopefully storyboarding will be an improvement over the existing IB options for building separate views based on device orientation.